# How to copy authored content data into a html form in AEM

Tags: aem, aem-6

How can I copy an authored content from my AEM touch UI textarea field to html form using javascript.
As soon as I press the submit button in the form, my authored data should be auto-populated into the texterea html form and submit it.

In angularjs is easy using $scope but how to do it in plain vanilla javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything, which is authored via Touch UI should be saved as property to a resource. This property can be read and when the page is rendered, the text will be written into the markup.